# Drawing a line in processing after a region of the screen has been pressed and the mouse is being clicked

Tags: processing

when i click the region it continually draws instead of when im holding the mouse. also ill figure out how to toggle the pencil when clicked later on. i am very new.

```
 void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseX > 772 && mouseX < 864 && mouseY > 1 && mouseY < 74) {
    //button 1 was just clicked, show button 2 instead
    drawPencil = true;
  }
  
    }
}
  



void draw() {
    if (drawPencil) {
       stroke(255);
    line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
    }        


}
```

Comment: please show your complete code

Answer (score 1):

I've written a small program which should give you an idea

```
boolean drawPencil;
 
void mousePressed() {
    drawPencil = true;
}

void mouseReleased()
{
   drawPencil = false;
}
  
void setup(){
    size(800,800);
}


void draw() {
    if (drawPencil) {
       stroke(255);
      line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
    }        
}
```

Comment: thanks. ive thought about your reply for a while and I still cant figure out how to get the correct behaviour. i get the desired behaviour while in the mouse coordinates however.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you do this. Here's a code snippet for you to experiment with. It'll react as follow:

[image: Lines]

```
float lastX, lastY;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);  
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  
  if (mousePressed) { // is true whenever a mouse button is held down
    stroke(255);
    line(mouseX, mouseY, lastX, lastY);
  }
}

void mousePressed() { // run once every click
  lastX = mouseX;
  lastY = mouseY;
}
```

Have fun!